# Loop does not iterate through entire array

Tags: php, loops

I need to save the contents of each of these Laravel models as json. This function should provide a nice shortcut:

```
public function ni()
{
    $filenames = array();
    $errors = array(); 

    foreach(glob(__DIR__.'\..\..\..\Models\CounterPoint\*') as $file) {
        $filename = preg_replace('/C:[\D]*\\\\/', '', $file);
        $filename = preg_replace('/.php/', '', $filename);
        if ($filename == 'CompositeKey' | $filename == 'Custom') {
            continue;
        }
        $filenames[] = $filename;
        unset($filename);
    }

    $len = count($filenames);
    echo "We have $len files.<br/><br/>";

    for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        echo "On iteration $i, file is $filenames[$i]<br/>";
        $model = '\App\Models\CounterPoint\\'.$filenames[$i];
        if ( $obj = $model::first() ) {
            $path = __DIR__.'\..\..\..\..\database\factories\seed_data\\'.$filenames[$i].'.json';
            file_put_contents($path, $obj);
            unset($obj);
        } else {
            $errors[] = $filenames[$i];
        }
    }
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $e) {
        print_r($e)."<br>";
    }
}
```

However, the output is as follows:

```
We have 102 files.
On iteration 0, file is ArAdjTrx
On iteration 1, file is ArCategCod
On iteration 2, file is ArCust
On iteration 3, file is ArCustProfCod
On iteration 4, file is ArMergeCust
On iteration 5, file is ArMergeCustGrp
On iteration 6, file is ArShipAdrs
On iteration 7, file is ArTaxCod
On iteration 8, file is ArTaxCodAuth
On iteration 9, file is CsosEcomConfigAttr
On iteration 10, file is CsosEcomConfigVal
On iteration 11, file is DbCtl
On iteration 12, file is DmSalStrItemDay
On iteration 13, file is EcCateg
```

There are no errors being thrown, and the files created so far are correct. I would like to know why it stops at 13 instead of `$len`. (Viewing the directory, one can see there are many more files.) Also notice `$errors` must be empty.

**I would like the loop to touch every file**, from `ArCategCod` to `UsrItemImages`.

Comment: maybe you reached the `max_execution_time` value.. I think it is set by default to 30 seconds.. try to increase it

Comment: @MateiMihai I just added `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300)` at the top of the function and `set_time_limit(30)` in the for loop. It did not change anything.